# Send mail from page using wp_mail

Tags: pages, forms, wp-mail

How do I call the WP_MAIL function from a page which has a form?

I would like to create a form in a page, and by pressing "Send" activate a function in the functions.php file, so the mail gets sent AND returning to a page where the form information is presented along with confirmation that the mail was actually sent.

Anybody

This is the form:

```
      <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET">
         Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" />
         Age: <input type = "text" name = "age" />
         <input type = "submit" />
      </form>
```

Catching this in the content page does not work, should this be placed in the functions.php?

```
<?php
   if( $_GET["name"] || $_GET["age"] ) {
      echo "Welcome ". $_GET['name']. "<br />";
      echo "You are ". $_GET['age']. " years old.";

      exit();
   }
?>
```

Comment: Use a `POST` form, and hook into `init`, check if the form is submitted by checking `isset( $_POST['SUBMIT_BTN_NAME_HERE'] )`. Also use nonces as they are good for security.

Answer (score 1):

This can (and should) be achieved using the `admin_post` action. Take a look at the docs for an example:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)

SitePoint also have a more comprehensive tutorial here:

https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Will this also work when the visitors are not logged in as administrators?

Comment: @user2975926 Yes it will.